App that is able to draw simplified objects easily
I'm attending to one competition where I can design some improvements in dosing nutritional supplements. Now, I have an idea of improvements, but I would like to present it better than with pen and paper.
Do you know some app (on Windows free, or on Linux free) that is able to create my schemes containing 3D objects into nice digital schemes? There are 3D objects, arrows, labels... maybe colors (but this is not important). It may/may not use AI.
So it can either convert my pen and paper drawings or it can draw.

From your very brief description of what you are looking for, Inkscape would appear to be an excellent choice. From your question, it appears that you are a first-timer to computer drawing and again, it would work for you.
Free on linux but donate if it is useful to you.

Look at "Logos By Nick" on youtube for a large number of tutorial type videos on Inkscape that will give you a good idea of whether it fits your needs.

@tckosvic Thank you, I will learn Inkscape.
